# Can SSRS XML data sources contain spatial data?

Tags: ssrs, xml, spatial

I've been given the task of producing a report which will extract data from a web service.

The web service provides data from a list of sites including aggregates. Lets say total sales by month.

Id like to plot these values on a map and locate them using geometry points.  The developer is investigating how he can include the spatial reference in the xml reply.

But before i get him change the Web service is there any limitation or restriction in ssrs that would stop this working?

If so, what are my alternatives? If i can retrieve the easting and northing in the xml can i convert to a spatial datatype with an expression on the fly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i have been able to read/research it seems that the answer is no. 
However i have found that I  can merge 2 datasets to achieve what I wanted to do.